# Counting specific cells

Tags: php, arrays, count

I currently have a 2 dimensional array that has data like this :

```
    X   X   X       X
    X   X   X       X
        X       X   X
        X   X   X   X
    X   X       X   X
    X   X   X   X   X
```

X marks a cell that has data, blank means its empty.
I having been pulling my hair for the last hour trying to figure out how to count what I call "holes".
It's basically a cell with empty data between two cells having data.
So by order you can see the cols have respectively 2, 0, 2, 0, 0 holes from left to right.
My function needs to return the total holes, so for this case 4.

Currently I have done this really close but my function is counting the 2 first cells on the 4th col which is wrong and I can't figure out how to account for that.

Here is my actual code :

```
public function countHoles(){
        $total = 0;
        for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
            $counting = false;
            $passed = false;
            for($j=0; $j<10; $j++){
                if(count($this->table[$j][$i])>0){
                    $passed = true;
                }
                if($passed && !$counting && count($this->table[$j][$i])==0){
                    $counting = true;
                }
                else{
                    $counting = false;
                }
                if($passed && $counting){
                    $total++;
                }
            }
        }
        return $total;
    }
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: How is the array being assigned values? Would the "holes" be null or nothing or either?

Comment: i might have forgot to mention that each cell is an array

what i am doing is just count its elements

so the "holes" would be identified by `count($this->table[$j][$i])==0`

Comment: @DanyKhalife: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @silent : oh thanks i thought you were referring to something else, this definitely shows how new i still am to this website :D

Comment: @bos: those in the 4th col do not count since they are not between Xs (they need to have an X before them to count)

Comment: In that case wouldn't it have 3 holes? 1 in the 1st column, 2 in the 3rd, and none in the 4th since the hole isn't between two data points?

Comment: @Ozzah : you are partially right
but for the first column there are 2 empty cells, they count as 2 (you counted them as 1) so thats why they are 4 in total :)

Comment: You know the reason Reina and I got confused is because you have "or more" there - as in "1 or more empty cells is a hole". If you're not grouping adjacent cells then it should be quite easy?

Comment: Ack, thanks for spotting that, i will edit my question
Im stumbled right now, sometimes its really easy and i am not concentrated to get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer in javascript, try this:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3,null,5],[1,2,3,null,5],[null,2,null,null,5],[null,2,3,4,null],[1,null,null,4,5],[1,2,3,4,null]];  
var hole = 0;   
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){        
    for(var j=1; j<arr[i].length-1; j++){
        if(arr[i][j]==null){
            for(var k=j;k<arr[i].length; k++){
                if(arr[i][k] != null){
                    k = arr[i].length;
                }else{
                    j++;                        
                }
            }
            if(j < arr[i].length){                  
                hole++;
            }
        }
    }
}
alert(hole);
```

'hole' is the var with the number of holes

Comment: thanks, this works fantastically if all holes were one by one
i've gotten through this part, the idea is it doesn't work if i have arr[i][j]==null and arr[i][j+1]==null for example
to illustrate this in a better way, the array is a schedule table by day and hour
each cell can have a course or more (the data) and so what i am doing here is finding how many free hours i have between 2 consecutive courses 
the result will go into another method which gets all possible schedules (which i have done already) and picks the one with the least number of holes 
Many thx for actually helping unlike othrs

Comment: Okay so to get this straight, you want to know if there's a whole that goes across two gaps but that's not at the beginning or the end? e.g. X 0 0 X X 0 (where 0 is null), in this instance there are 2 holes? or two holes are counted as one? I'm a bit confused lol

Comment: sorry for the confusion :( 
yes what you said is correct, and these count as 2 holes not one :)

Comment: take your time, like i said this is not a homework, not a job... 
i will also get back it at tomorrow too, maybe i'll wake up mysteriously with a solution as most of the time lol

Comment: I've just updated my solution, try it? I didn't test it too much but it seemed to work on the surface

Comment: Thanks again Reina your answer gave actually the closest results to the right answers when i did my tests today
it still has some specific cases where it failed, but they are very minor so i can take care of that...
once again, many thanks on my behalf, i wish all people where like you :)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you just want to know how many empty cells you have in your array which isn't on an edge.

Similar to counting the number of spaces in a sentence, but not counting the whitespace at the beginning or end?

```
public function countHoles()
{
  $total = 0;

  // Start at 1 and go to Count() - 2
  for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)   // Horizontal
    for($j = 1; $j < 9; $j++) // Vertical
    {
      if (j == 1) // 2nd row
      {
        if ($this->table[$i][$j] == null && $this->table[$i][0] != null)
          $total++;
      }
      else if (j == 3) // 2nd last row
      {
        if ($this->table[$i][$j] == null && $this->table[$i][4] != null)
          $total++;
      }
      else
      {
        if ($this->table[$i][$j] == null)
          $total++;
      }
    }

  return $total;
}
```

Is this what you mean?

(You may need to replace the `== null` and `!= null` with whatever other 'emptyness' check you need. Also, the nested IFs can obviously be condensed - I wrote them expanded for ease of understanding.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was giving really close counts but it failed on some of the 800+ combinations when i did my tests so i guess i will use Reina's answer since it was closer, but again many thanks, i really appreciate it